# FSharp Functional Composition

Tags: f#

I have three functions like this:

```
let functionA (i:int) =
    "functionA" + string i

let functionB (i:int) =
    "functionB" + string i

let functionC (i:int) =
    "functionC" + string i
```

I want to chain these functions together such that the result of executing all three is an array of each of the return values, kind of like
Seq.Collect arrayOfFunctions

Is there a way to do this declaratively?  If I change functionB's parameter from an int to a float, does the answer change?

Thanks

Comment: Not quite clear for me. Is this you want to do? `let farr = [| functionA; functionB; functionC |]
let applyfarr farr i = Array.map (fun f -> f i) farr`

Comment: `applyfarr farr 2`  `> 
val it : string [] = [|"functionA2"; "functionB2"; "functionC2"|]`

Comment: Yeah.  Figured that out!  Thanks, I think that is it!  Can you reply and I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let farr = [| functionA; functionB; functionC |] 
let applyfarr farr i = Array.map (fun f -> f i) farr
```

How to apply:

```
applyfarr farr 2 
> val it : string [] = [|"functionA2"; "functionB2"; "functionC2"|]
```