# FSharp Functional Composition: Threading an accumlator

Tags: f#

I have asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236710/fsharp-functional-composition).  I want to do a similar thing but this time thread an accumulator though the array of functions.  I immediately thought of Array.Reduce or Array.Fold but they are not working for me:

```
let AddTen x =
    x + 10

let MultiplyFive x =
    x * 5

let SubtractTwo x =
    x - 2

let functionArray = [| AddTen; MultiplyFive; SubtractTwo |] 
let calculateAnswer functionArray x = functionArray |>Array.reduce(fun acc f -> f acc)
```

The last line throws this exception:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       'a -> 'b     but given a
>       'b     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''b -> 'a'

Am I thinking about the problem incorrectly?

Comment: 1) You're not using `x`. 2) `Array.reduce` has the signature `('T -> 'T -> 'T) -> 'T [] -> 'T`, i.e. both arguments to your lambda must be the same type. Do you want `Array.fold`?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out with Array.fold either.  I need to start with the input paramater and then invoke each function in turn using the output of the prior function as input into the next function

Comment: Note that I can do it via functional composition and pipelining, I am just trying out a different way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these two:

```
let calculateReduce = functionArray |> Array.reduce (fun f g -> f >> g)
let calculateFold x = functionArray |> Array.fold (fun acc f -> f acc) x
```

In the reduce version, you take an array of functions and compose them into a single function which you can later call on `x`.

In the fold version you fold over the array of functions, threading the accumulator through and applying each function to it in sequence. `x` is the initial value of the accumulator here.

Your original code didn't work, because a reduce expects a `'a -> 'a -> 'a` function, which in case of an array of functions would imply composition, while you were trying to apply one function of type `int -> int` to another.